# Regex to get html element content by class

Tags: php, regex

I've seen a few questions like this with the accepted answers being to use a HTML parser. BUT if I HAD to use regex (php), how could I get the `span` text in the below examples based on the class name.

1. `<span class="phone-number" data-id="999" style="{lots of random stuff here}">+61 9900 0000</span>`
2. `<span class="email" data-something="xxx" style="{lots of random stuff here}">test@test.com</span>`

So my variables would be element type and class name.

With my basic knowledge, I've gotten this far:

`(?<=span class="phone-number")\s+(.*?)(?=<\/span>)`

but that includes the data and style attributes.

Comment: I don't think regex is the best option here. Why not use a DOM parser?

Comment: I just pasted this in another question. So here it is to you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: There's a reason every experienced developer says not to use regex to parse HTML. Trust the experience and use a parser. If you think you can't use a parser, can you explain why not?

Comment: There is no reason not to use a parser, considering DOMDocument is built in and requires no external libs. Regex is the wrong tool for HTML as HTML is too volatile.

Comment: @jhilgeman my reason is this: all other matching mechanisms in this existing application use regex on text versions of HTML emails. These patterns are stored in an array for easy access and are chosen depending on input. The raw HTML is available (as plain text won't work for this particular email) but the program flow must use the regex array or else it must be completely re-written.

Comment: Is there any issue with `(?<=<span class="phone-number")(?:.*?)(?<=>)(.*?)(?=<\/span>)` (https://regex101.com/r/vb8d7X/1/)

Comment: Why not just detect the HTML and add a different flow / processing function for that scenario so the existing text emails continue to work as-is?

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are because people don't like the question. There is nothing wrong with the question at all. I know I should use DOM parsing but I don't have that option so the question is about how to use regex in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex to parse HTML, instead you should use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

```
<?php
$html = '
<span class="phone-number" data-id="999" style="{lots of random stuff here}">+61 9900 0000</span>
<span class="email" data-something="xxx" style="{lots of random stuff here}">test@test.com</span>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$phone = $xpath->query("//span[contains(@class, 'phone-number')]");
$email = $xpath->query("//span[contains(@class, 'email')]");

echo $phone->item(0)->nodeValue.PHP_EOL; //+61 9900 0000
echo $email->item(0)->nodeValue.PHP_EOL; //test@test.com

/*
// loop if have multiple
foreach ($phone as $value) {
    echo $value->nodeValue;
}
*/
```

https://3v4l.org/qbVaS

Comment: This will be helpful for future endeavors when I have the option to use HTML parsing.